# Hide WinXP Mode host in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machines, network-share, windows

I have an IP cam that can access WinXP shares but not Win 7 shares. That's why I'm running the WinXP Mode VM. (I've tried a million tweaks to Win7's sharing settings, but the IP cam just won't connect)
I'd like to have it running (shares accessible), but hidden somewhere in the tray, or maybe running as a service.

Any idea how I can do that? An out-of-the box Win7 solution would be preferred, but any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 2):

RBTray may be able to minimize your XP mode to tray.  See: http://rbtray.sourceforge.net/

The problem with the IP cam connecting to Windows 7 shares may perhaps be solved as well though potentially out of scope here.  Would have been helpful if you had posted the make/model.  The cam not connecting is likely a permission problem and not a protocol problem.

Comment: Not sure if the 'cam not connecting' question fits SF.com . Maybe more suited to superuser.com. I don't think it's due to permissions - I managed to make a Win7 share completely RW-able anonymously. I've connected to it from another Win7 machine as well as from a WinXP machine, and I could write to it.

Comment: I followed my own advice and posted to SU - http://superuser.com/questions/375755/connect-trendnet-ip-cam-to-windows-7-share